# Creating an image with layer support with Image Magick

Tags: macos, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I've tried to create a transparent image that I will be able to open and paste a logo into.
It created a bitmap image with no layer support.  So when I opened it in Photoshop:

- It was labeled as "Bitmap"
- It had a black background, and a locked layer that I couldn't delete or edit.

I tried to change the colorspace, but that didn't help.  I'm not sure what else to try.  I could try creating a .PSD instead, but I don't really want to do it that way.

Here's what I tried.

```
convert -size 192x192 -colorspace RGB xc:transparent apple-touch-icon-192x192.png
```

How can I create an image that allows creating layers in Photoshop?

Comment: You do not believe that you can create a transparent background layer by importing a png. Photoshop sees transparent pngs normally as channel masks or alpha channels. Photoshop has a special background transparency that is different from alpha channels or layer masks. I am not an expert on Photoshop, so I will defer to anyone who knows if this can be done. If you import a transparent png with at least one opaque pixel, then it will look proper and not be recognized as a bitmap. For example `convert -size 256x256 xc:transparent -size 1x1 xc:black -compose over -composite layer.png`.

Comment: CONTINUED: you can do your command and save as either PSD or TIFF and that will work when you import into Photoshop. You will get a proper transparent layer.

Comment: Awesome!  :) 
That's exactly what I needed!  Thanks a lot!